# Ajax JSON and jsp

Tags: ajax, json, jsp

I have created a Form data page using JSP and apply ajax call and want to store data in MS access but i found some difficulty as form data does not store and even console doesn't show any error..
please guide me..

My login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
 <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

       function sendData()
       {
              alert("I m in SendData Function");
              var email=$('#email').val();
              var name=$('#name').val();
              var password=$('#password').val();

              alert("i am in senddata mode");
              var jsonDataObject=new Object();
              alert(" JSON call");
              jsonDataObject.name=name;
              jsonDataObject.email=email;
              jsonDataObject.password=password;


        var jsonString= JSON.stringify(jsonDataObject);
        alert("Before Ajax call");

        $.ajax({

                     type:"POST",

                     url:"localhost:8080/RestDemo/UserInfoService",

                     dataType:"json",
                     data:jsonString

       });

              alert("After Ajax Call Send Data");

}      
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#D8D8D8>
<form name="form"  method="post" onsubmit="sendData()">
<div style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:110px;background-color:#5FB404;padding:20px;width:650px;height:450px" >
<h1><center> Login Registration Form</center></h1>
<pre>
<p style="font-size:20px">
NAME          :<input type="text" name="name" id="name" ><br>
EMAIL         :<input type="text" name="email" id="email" ><br>
PASSWORD      :<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"  style="padding:7px"></center>

</p></pre>

 </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

2.Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RestDemo</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>Service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

3.UserInfo.java

```
package Service;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

@Path("/UserInfoService")


public class UserInfo {

    @POST

    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    //@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)


    public void setDetails(@FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("email") String email,
              @FormParam("password") String password) 
    {
        UserDetailsDao userDetailsDao=new UserDetailsDaoImpl();
        userDetailsDao.getUserDetails(name, email, password);
    }
}
```

4.UserDetailDao.java

```
package Service;

public interface UserDetailsDao {
    public void getUserDetails(String name,String email,String password);

}
```

5.UserDetailDaoImpl.java

```
package Service;
import java.sql.*;

public class UserDetailsDaoImpl implements UserDetailsDao {


    @Override
    public void getUserDetails(String name, String email, String password) 
    {
          System.out.println("Test");
               try
               {
                    Connection conn;
                    Statement stmt;
                    ResultSet rs;
               Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
               conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DataInsert","","");
               stmt=conn.createStatement();

               int nrow=stmt.executeUpdate("Insert into UserTable values('"+name+"','"+email+"','"+password+"')");
              if(nrow>0)
               {       
               System.out.println("Record Inserted");
               }
               rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM UserTable");
               while(rs.next())
               {
                  String getName = rs.getString(1);
                  String getEmail = rs.getString(2);
                  String getPassword = rs.getString(3);

               System.out.println(getName+"     "+getEmail+"         "+getPassword);
              }
             rs.close();
             stmt.close();
             conn.close();

             }   //end of try block 
             catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
             {

            e.printStackTrace();

            }
            catch(SQLException w)
            {
            w.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Please format your code and state your problem . _Have you tried debugging?_

Comment: please guide what should be the URL in the ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change this URL `url:"localhost:8080/RestDemo/UserInfoService"` in the ajax post, should be the url pattern for the mapped servlet file in `Web.xml`

```
 $.ajax({
                     type:"POST",
                     url:"/UserInfoService",
                     dataType:"json",
                     data:jsonString

       });
```

Try `/rest/UserInfoService` if the above one doesnt work.

<sub>i expect you are calling the `UserInfo` from your jsp file</sub>

Comment: Thanku for your response..it realy helped me..program works..But the data inserted through the jsp page in MS access appears as NULL.Is there is any problem in Ajax call or in sql or in connection? please guide me

Comment: Any excpetions ? check for the datatypes in the database

Comment: It works when i send data in form of array instead of using stringify function :
var arr = {"name":  name,
                      "email": email,
                      "password": password              
                        };

Comment: Thanks @ San krish :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  New login.jsp page

   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

       function sendData()
       {
              alert("I m in SendData Function");
              var email=$('#email').val();
              var name=$('#name').val();
              var password=$('#password').val();


              alert("i am in SendData mode");

              var arr = {"name":  name,
                      "email": email,
                      "password": password              
                        };



        alert("Before Ajax call");

        $.ajax({

                     type:"POST",

                     url:"rest/UserInfoService",

                     dataType:"json",
                     data:arr


       });

              alert("After Ajax Call Send Data");

}      
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#D8D8D8>
<form name="form"  method="post" onsubmit="sendData()">
<div style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:110px;background-color:#5FB404;padding:20px;width:650px;height:450px" >
<h1><center> Login Registration Form</center></h1>
<pre>
<p style="font-size:20px">
NAME          :<input type="text" name="name" id="name" ><br>
EMAIL         :<input type="text" name="email" id="email" ><br>
PASSWORD      :<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"  style="padding:7px"></center>

</p></pre>

 </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```